# Efficient thread use on high traffic ASP.NET Core Web API with processing timeout

Tags: asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

My ASP.NET Core Web API (Linux) endpoint needs to serve a high volume of concurrent requests. If the request takes more than 200ms then it should abort and return a custom piece of JSON. The code is all awaitable. The request must always return HTTP 200 and the HTTP request timeout cannot be reduced from 30 secs to 200ms.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish what I want? Should I use a Task? Should I use `Task.Wait` or `Task.WaitAsync`? Or should the work methods run in the HTTP request thread, periodically check `Stopwatch.Elapsed` and throw a timeout exception?

This is my current code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    // Processing part 1
    var result1 = await DoWorkPart1("Param1");

    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested())
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Processing part 2    
    var result2 = wait DoWorkPart2(result1);
    
    return result2;
}).Unwrap();    // Return lambda task, not outer task

// Is it better to use WaitAsync?
task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));

if (task.IsCompleted)   // Result within timeout
{
    if (task.Exception == null) // Success
    {
        return Ok(task.Result);
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(new FailedObject() { Reason = ReasonEnum.UnexpectedError };
    }
}
else   // Timeout
{
    return OK(new FailedObject() { Reason = ReasonEnum.TookTooLong };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most efficient way to accomplish what I want?

I recommend using `CancellationToken`s to cancel. With a very short timeout like 200ms, you might just want to create a `CancellationTokenSource` with that timeout and ignore the `CancellationToken` provided to you by ASP.NET, which handles situations like clients disconnecting early.

> Should I use a Task? Should I use Task.Wait or Task.WaitAsync? Or should the work methods run in the HTTP request thread, periodically check Stopwatch.Elapsed and throw a timeout exception?

I would say none of these. Instead, pass the `CancellationToken` down as far as you possibly can, ideally right to the lowest-level APIs your asynchronous code is calling.

If some of those APIs ignore their cancellation tokens, or if it's possible they may complete synchronously (e.g., due to caching), then adding `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` in-between steps is a good idea.

Side note: Don't use `StartNew`.

```
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
try
{
  // Processing part 1
  var result1 = await DoWorkPart1("Param1", cts.Token);

  cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  // Processing part 2    
  var result2 = wait DoWorkPart2(result1, cts.Token);

  return Ok(result2);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
  return OK(new FailedObject() { Reason = ReasonEnum.TookTooLong };
}
catch
{
  return Ok(new FailedObject() { Reason = ReasonEnum.UnexpectedError };
}
```